# Does Android SurfaceView use the usual openGL es Calls?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-canvas, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

currently I switched from using glSurfaceView to SurfaceView for my app
I was wandering however if the internal process of SurfaceView just uses the 
opengl es calls that were used in glSurfaceView

for Example, in glSurfaceView you have to give a float value range between(0.0`1.0) for the uv Coords

However in Surface View you can use Rects with int values directly pointing to the pixel coordinates of the bitmap image. it seems more efficient, However if the coordinates have to be converted to floats afterwards to fit into the opengl es function, it would be a waste of processing right?

I;m just a newb just want to know how these all work internally.

Answer (score 2):

It uses the same OpenGL ES calls if you use the same OpenGL ES calls.  GLSurfaceView is just a library of classes that wraps SurfaceView, and handles the EGL setup and thread management for you.  You can use GLES with SurfaceView yourself (see [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) for examples).

If you're drawing on the SurfaceView's Surface with Canvas, then you are rendering in software with the Skia library, and OpenGL ES is not involved at all.

If you're drawing on a custom View with Canvas, then hardware acceleration may be involved, and your Canvas draw calls are performed by GLES.  Converting coordinates between numeric formats is one of the less expensive parts of the operation.

To learn how things work internally, see the [graphics architecture doc](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html).

Answer (score 0):

Android internally might or might not use `OpenGL` calls with surface view. There is one software renderer called `SKIA` available to android for rendering purposes when hardware acceleration is explicitly turned off in app OR its not possible to use hardware acceleration because of view dimensions/format etc.